# How to call spring service (RequestParam ) from in java script function (Error 400: Required String parameter 'flag' is not present)

Tags: javascript, java

I want to call a spring service from script function ,but i am unable to call my service for below code. Can you please suggest me i am doing correct or wrong.

```
Controller class:

@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public String downloadFile(@RequestParam String flag, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    return flag;
}

    <script>
    function downloadPdf(flag) {

         if (flag == 'PRINT') {
            redirectUrl = "download.htm/flag=" + flag;
            var myWindow = window.open(redirectUrl , '',
                    'width=200,height=100');
            myWindow.focus();
            myWindow.print();
        }
    }
</script>
```

When run my code i facing issue like

> Error 400: Required String parameter 'flag' is not present

Comment: You did not give a string parameter named flag in your redirect url. It might help to understand how to add query strings to your url.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can mark the `@RequestParam` as `required=false` *(default value is true)*.
2. If you are using a query parameter on the URL, the URL should be something like `download.html?flag=value` not `download.html/flag=value`. What you have on the example is a weird mix between `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`.